# How to put 2 html pages on a nodeJS server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server

I'm learning NodeJS and Javascript and I would like to build a simple server that runs 2 HTML pages, one that opens with `localhost:3000/index` and the other with `localhost:3000/about`.

I know how to have my server showing one HTML page but I struggle to add another one. I tried an `if` statement but it doesn't work. Here is my code :

```
let http = require("http");
let fs = require("fs");
let port = 3000;
let url = require("url");

let server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
  if (page == "/index") {
    fs.readFile("index.html", (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        response.writeHead(404);
        response.end("This file doesn't exist");
      } else {
        response.writeHead(200, {
          "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"
        });
      }
    });
  } else if (page == "/about") {
    fs.readFile("about.html", (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        response.writeHead(404);
        response.end("This file doesn't exist");
      } else {
        response.writeHead(200, {
          "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"
        });
      }
    });
  }

  response.end(data);
});

server.listen(port);
```

Thank you very much for an help you can give me.
Good day,

Comment: Your variable `page` in the if-statement is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `page` variable that's not defined, you should use `request.url` and compare it.

`request.url` is the full URL without the server, protocol or port.

Answer (score 0):

you can put , both your pages on a public folder and serve them, you dont have to hard code a url for every single page. and with this way your code look cleaner.
In the example below , assuming that `public_html` is the folder where your htlm pages are located

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.set("port",process.env.PORT||3000)
var server = app.listen(app.get("port"),()=>{
  console.log("Listening on PORT: "+ app.get("port"))
});
app.use("/",express.static('public_html'))//you put here your htlm pages
```